# Error: IOStream has no fileno - SUMO

Tags: python

I am trying to run SUMO through traci interface. I copy pasted this example from this [link](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Interfacing_TraCI_from_Python). The code is as follows

```
import os, sys
import subprocess

if 'SUMO_HOME' in os.environ:
     tools = os.path.join(os.environ['SUMO_HOME'], 'tools')
     sys.path.append(tools)
else:   
     sys.exit("please declare environment variable 'SUMO_HOME'")

PORT = 8813
sumoBinary = "C:/Program Files (x86)/DLR/Sumo/bin/sumo-gui"
sumoProcess = subprocess.Popen([sumoBinary, "-c", "example.sumocfg", \
        "--remote-port", str(PORT)], stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr)


import traci
import traci.constants as tc

traci.init(PORT)
traci.vehicle.subscribe(vehID, (tc.VAR_ROAD_ID, tc.VAR_LANEPOSITION))
print(traci.vehicle.getSubscriptionResults(vehID))

for step in range(3):
    print("step", step)
    traci.simulationStep()
    print(traci.vehicle.getSubscriptionResults(vehID))

traci.close()
```

When I try to run the code, it throws me the following error

```
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 85, in execfile
exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Raja/Documents/vehicomPhd/SUMOTraffic/traci.py", line 22, in <module>
"--remote-port", str(PORT)], stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 823, in __init__
errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1037, in _get_handles
c2pwrite = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(stdout.fileno())

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\zmq\iostream.py", line 205, in fileno
raise UnsupportedOperation("IOStream has no fileno.")

UnsupportedOperation: IOStream has no fileno.
```

Anyone know what is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're running in an `ipython` notebook. They have non-standard "standard" I/O streams that can't be used like a "true" file object (because they're really data queues, not pipes, so they don't have a file descriptor to use for low level I/O).

You can't use them with libraries (like `subprocess`) that perform low level I/O; [the error is there to tell you this.](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/3072/). You'll need to use a real file-like object, possibly something as simple as sending output to a `tempfile.TemporaryFile` and then copying output from the file to `stdout` if that's what you need.

It's possible it would work by just not passing `Popen` `stdout` and `stderr` arguments at all; the default behavior for `subprocess` is to use the same `stdout` and `stderr` as the parent, so if there are valid file handles opened (even if the notebook replaced `sys.stdout`/`sys.stderr` for Python use), it might "just work" (where "just work" includes the possibility that data sent to the underlying file descriptors `0` and `1` is discarded, so you never see it).

Or just don't run in the ipython notebook.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I replaced `stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr` with `stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and it does not show up this error. However, I now have a different error. 
`File "C:/Users/Raja/Documents/vehicomPhd/SUMOTraffic/traci.py", line 28, in <module>
    traci.init(8813)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\DLR\Sumo\tools\traci\__init__.py", line 469, in init
    return getVersion()
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly`

Comment: @Mechanic: Not enough context to give you anything definite, but stuff that springs to mind: 1. You're running a version of `traci` that's written for Python 2 on a Python 3 interpreter (which often just dies with `SyntaxError`s, but not always) 2. You're using the `PIPE`-ed handles (binary mode), or data from them (`bytes`), in a context that requires text mode handles or `str` data. If that's the case, the simplest fix is to pass [`universal_newlines=True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) to the `Popen` constructor to open text mode streams.

Comment: The problem is due to the incosistence between Python 2 and 3 and you rightly pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my command line used Python 2 whereas the spyder IDE used python 3. Since I wont be needing to pass any more arguments to the stdin, I removed the option and simply tried to open the sumo-gui with `subprocess` as follows. It works now.

```
PORT = 8813
sumoBinary = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/DLR/Sumo/bin/sumo-gui'
sumoProcess = subprocess.Popen([sumoBinary, "-c", "Kaiserslautern.sumocfg", \
        "--remote-port", str(PORT)])
```